# Segmentation Fault strcpy and fscanf

Tags: segmentation-fault

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char *phrase = NULL;
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", phrase) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        n -> next = NULL;
        strcpy(n -> word, phrase);

        int index = hash(phrase);

        if (table[index] -> next == NULL)
        {
            table[index] = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n -> next = table[index] -> next;
            table[index] = n;
        }
        free(n);
    }
    return true;

}
```

Hey guys. My valgrind is returning a segmentation fault in strcpy. My understanding is that it's because phrase is NULL. But why won't fscanf copy the string into phrase?

Comment: You’ve just said the reason- phrase is a null pointer. You need to allocate a block of memory and have it point to that. See this example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: I guess I just have no idea why considering 1. I initialized as NULL and 2. I wrote to it using fscanf, why its returning a segmentation fault. I checked out the example and it seems like its doing something similar?

Comment: See this line: fscanf (pFile, "%s", str); str is a char buffer of 80 bytes